# Can we multiple condition in PHP?

Tags: php, optimization, conditional-statements

I am front of reflexion about my php developments. I'm trying to optimize my code.

I have often condition like this :

```
if($userConnected->getType() == User::BUYER_ACCOUNT_TYPE || $userConnected->getType() == User::ADMIN_ACCOUNT_TYPE){//Mycode}
```

My question is : **Is it possible to have something like this :**

```
if($userConnected->getType() == User::BUYER_ACCOUNT_TYPE || User::ADMIN_ACCOUNT_TYPE)
```

Actually the best way I found to do this is :

```
if(in_array($userConnected->getType(), array(User::BUYER_ACCOUNT_TYPE, User::ADMIN_ACCOUNT_TYPE)))
```

And I want to know if there is a better way ?

Thank you in advance

Thomas

Comment: The first and third ways seem to make sense, what's wrong with them?  The second way probably doesn't do what you expect, since `User::ADMIN_ACCOUNT_TYPE` isn't really a true/false value.

Comment: Personally i would do that with `in_array` like you mentioned.

Comment: the 1st method is quick and clear the third method is less obvious what it is doing at a glance

Comment: I know that the first and third solution work, my question is there is a better way to have something closer to the second one

Answer (score 1):

You can add some public methods to your User class to check if the user is a buyer or an admin:

```
public function isBuyer()
{
    return $this->type === self::BUYER_ACCOUNT_TYPE;
}

public function isAdmin()
{
    return $this->type === self::ADMIN_ACCOUNT_TYPE;
}
```

Having these methods you can simply check:

```
if ($userConnected->isBuyer() || $userConnected->isAdmin())
```

You can go further and do a single method if the condition above is used very often:

```
public function isAllowed() // just an example of a method name
{
     return $this->isBuyer() || $this->isAdmin();
}
```

Comment: +1 this bad boy. These methods will then return true or false which you can then check. In terms of optimising for speed, this would be slightly slower. But improved the readability massively!